Segmentation fault (core dumped) new to c
As the title says I get a Segmentation fault (Core dumped) output. I've used a debugger and all but I haven't had the clue to why it is doing it. I am somewhat new to C so any help would be appreiciated.
The program is supposed to:
Read Questions: It reads a set of survey questions from an input and categorizes them as either "Direct" or "Reverse."
Read Responses: It processes the survey responses (e.g., "fully disagree," "agree," etc.), converts them into numerical values, and stores them for each respondent.
Calculate Frequencies: It calculates and prints the frequency of responses for each question. If the question is marked as "Reverse," the responses are adjusted accordingly (e.g., reverse scoring).
Calculate Scores: It computes and prints the scores for each respondent across different categories (e.g., Confidence, Interest, Gender, Usefulness, Professionalism) based on their answers to the survey.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXR 100
#define MAXQ 50

//define constants for the questions
#define DIRECT 0
#define REVERSE 1

//the arrays to hold the questions
char questions[MAXQ][256];
int q_type[MAXQ]; //0 for direct 1 for reverse
int responses[MAXR][MAXQ]; //array to hold the responses

//function to read the questions
void readquestions(){
    
    char buffer[4096];

 //reading questiosn from input
    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
        int i = 0;

        while (token != NULL && i < MAXQ){
            strcpy(questions[i], token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            i++;
        }
    }

    //reads question type
    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
        int i = 0;  

        while(token != NULL && i < MAXQ){
            if(strcmp(token, "Reverse") == 0){
                q_type[i] = REVERSE;
            }else{
                q_type[i] = DIRECT;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            i++;
        }
    }
    /*//for loop that counts how many questions are read
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXQ; i++){
        q_type[i] = 0; // initialize as not REVERSE
        snprintf(questions[i], 256, "Questions %d", i + 1);
    }*/
}

//function to read responses
void readresponses(int *num_respondents){
    char buffer[4096]; //holds each line of responses
    *num_respondents = 0;

    //for loop to process responses
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
        if(buffer[0] == '#') continue; //skip comment lines

        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");

        //skip demographic fields
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(token == NULL) break;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }

        if(token == NULL){
            continue;
        } //skips if there are no responses

        //parse respones
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXQ; i++){
            if(token == NULL) break;

            if(strcmp(token, "fully disagree") == 0){
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 1;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "disagree") == 0){
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 2;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "partially disagree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 3;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "partially agree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 4;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "agree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 5;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "fully agree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 6;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ","); //move to next response
        }
        (*num_respondents)++;
    }
}

//this function calculates the frequencies
void calculatefrequencies(int num_questions, int num_respondents){
    //simple if statement to return function if theres no respondents
    if(num_respondents == 0){
        printf("No respondents to calculate frequencies\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("FREQUENCIES ARE COMPUTED FOR EACH LEVEL OF AGREEMENT BELOW\n\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < num_questions; i++){
        int freq[6] = {0}; // freq. for the 6 likert levels

        //for loop to count the freq .of each response
        for(int j = 0; j < num_respondents; j++){
            int response = responses[j][i];
            if(q_type[i] == REVERSE){//if reverse-scored
                response = 7 - response;
            }//this reverses the score if its a reverse question
        freq[response - 1]++;
        }

    //to print relative frequencies
    printf("%s\n", questions[i]);
    for(int z = 0; z < 6; z++){
    double percent = (num_respondents > 0) ? (freq[z] * 100.0) / num_respondents : 0.0;
        printf("%.2f: %s\n", percent, (z == 0) ? "fully disagree" :
                          (z == 1) ? "disagree" :
                          (z == 2) ? "partially disagree" :
                          (z == 3) ? "partially agree" :
                          (z == 4) ? "agree" : "fully agree");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//function to calculate and print scores for each respondent
void calculatescores(int num_questions, int num_respondents){
    if(num_respondents == 0){
    return;
    }

    printf("SCORES FOR ALL THE RESPONDENT\n");

    //looping through each respondent and to compute scores
    for (int r = 0; r < num_respondents; r++){
        int total_c = 0, total_i = 0, total_g = 0, total_u = 0, total_p = 0;

        for(int q = 0; q < num_questions; q++){
            int score = responses[r][q];
            if(q_type[q] == REVERSE){
                score = 7 - score; //reverse the score if needed
            }

    //categorization
        if (q < 8) total_c += score;      // Confidence
                else if (q < 18) total_i += score; // Interest
            else if (q < 28) total_g += score; // Gender
                else if (q < 34) total_u += score; // Usefulness
                else total_p += score;             // Professionalism
        }
        printf("C:%d, I:%d, G:%d, U:%d, P:%d\n", total_c, total_i, total_g, total_u, total_p);
    }
}


int main() {
    int num_questions = 0;
    int num_respondents = 0;

    readquestions(); //read question from input

    //for loop to count how many questions are read
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXQ; i++){
        if(questions[i][0] != '\0'){
        num_questions++;
        }
    }
    readresponses(&num_respondents); //read responses from input
    calculatefrequencies(num_questions, num_respondents); //calculate frequencies
    calculatescores(num_questions, num_respondents); //calculate  scores

    //checks for debugging
    //printf("Number of questions: %d\n", num_questions);
    //printf("Number of respondents: %d\n", num_respondents);

 return 0;
}
`


What exact input are you giving the program when it core dumps?

"As the title says I get a Segmentation fault (Core dumped)" That's just another way of saying "I got some memory-related bug", it's not a helpful problem description or title.

Earlier (in comments removed as it was in Staging Grounds) you wrote you cannot provide the input because it is multiple files. Then you should reduce the amount of input to the minimum. That is part of creating a minimum reproducible example. Also, during the process of reducing both your code and input you will learn about the issue and even may be able to solve it without asking a question here at all.

Code has at least these problems:
fgets() saves the '\n'
if(strcmp(token,... tree all fail as token may have a '\n'.  See Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input or consider strtok(buffer, ",\n");
Code should complain if there are no matches.  Maybe a no-match condition also leads to OP's UB?
Potential buffer overflow
strcpy(questions[i], token); risks overflowing questions[i].
Simply alternative: snprintf(questions[i], sizeof questions[i], "%s", token);.
Other more elegant approaches exist - but tend to be more than 1 line.
IAC, code should additionally detect the excessively long string and complain.
Perhaps other issues

Try to fix your implicit causes of the segmentation fault in your functions, act accordingly. (initialized memory and avoid buffer overflow)
//function to read the questions
void readquestions() {
    char buffer[4096];

    //reading questiosn from input
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
        int i = 0;

        while (token != NULL && i < MAXQ) {
            strncpy(questions[i], token, 255);
            questions[i][255] = '\0';
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            i++;
        }
    }

    //reads question type
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
        int i = 0;

        while (token != NULL && i < MAXQ) {
            if (strcmp(token, "Reverse") == 0) {
                q_type[i] = REVERSE;
            } else {
                q_type[i] = DIRECT;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            i++;
        }
    }
}

//function to read responses
void readresponses(int *num_respondents){
    char buffer[4096]; //holds each line of responses
    *num_respondents = 0;

    //for loop to process responses
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
        if(buffer[0] == '#') continue; //skip comment lines

        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");

        //skip demographic fields
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(token == NULL) break;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }

        if(token == NULL){
            continue;
        } //skips if there are no responses

        //parse respones
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXQ; i++){
            if(token == NULL) break;

            if(strcmp(token, "fully disagree") == 0){
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 1;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "disagree") == 0){
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 2;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "partially disagree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 3;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "partially agree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 4;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "agree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 5;
            }else if(strcmp(token, "fully agree") == 0) {
                responses[*num_respondents][i] = 6;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ","); //move to next response
        }
        (*num_respondents)++;
    
        if (*num_respondents >= MAXR) {
            printf("Max number of respondents reached: %d\n", MAXR);
            break;
        }
     }
}

....

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXQ; i++) {
        questions[i][0] = '\0';  // Set the first character to null
        q_type[i] = DIRECT;      // Initialize as DIRECT (default)
    }

    int num_questions = 0;
    int num_respondents = 0;

    ....
}

